# MySQLi Query - while result color alternative table rows

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

This is something pretty basic but I am stumped, maybe someone can point me in the right direction why this is not working?

I running a MySQL query that returns 5 rows which then are echoed into a table. After each row output, I am changing the row bgcolor to alternate and make it more readable, only the code does not seem to work as I see all rows in the same color. I tried 2 options but neither works, appreciate any guidance.

Option 1 - array with colors

```
// query database
if (!$result8 = $conn->query($sql8)) {
    die('There was an error running SQL query #8 [' . $conn->error . ']');
}

// define alternating row background colors
$rowColors = Array('#EEEEEE','#FFFFFF');
$i = 0;

// output all string categories in array
while ($row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dml_problem_mbr = $row8['Count_Member'];
    $dml_problem_mbr_pc = round(($dml_problem_mbr / $dml_problem_total) * 100);

    $body_message .= "
        <tr bgcolor=\"" . $rowColors[$i++ % count($rowColors)] . "\" style=\"-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;\">
            <td width=\"50%\" align=\"left\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-right: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
                ".$dml_problem_name. "
            </td>
            <td width=\"16.67%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
                ".$dml_problem_total. "
            </td>
            <td width=\"16.67%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
                ".$dml_problem_mbr." (".$dml_problem_mbr_pc. "%)
            </td>
            <td width=\"25%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
                3,000 THB
            </td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Option 2 - define colors in variable

```
// query database
if (!$result8 = $conn->query($sql8)) {
die('There was an error running SQL query #8 [' . $conn->error . ']');
}

// set counter to 0
$i = 0;

// output all string categories in array
while ($row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dml_problem_mbr = $row8['Count_Member'];
    $dml_problem_mbr_pc = round(($dml_problem_mbr / $dml_problem_total) * 100);

    // adjust bgcolor of row
    if ($i % 2 == 0) { $bgcolor = "#FFFFFF"; } else { $bgcolor = "#EEEEEE"; }
    $i++;


    $body_message .= "
    <tr bgcolor=\"" . $bgcolor . "\" style=\"-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;\">
        <td width=\"50%\" align=\"left\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-right: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
            ".$dml_problem_name. "
        </td>
        <td width=\"16.67%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
            ".$dml_problem_total. "
        </td>
        <td width=\"16.67%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
            ".$dml_problem_mbr." (".$dml_problem_mbr_pc. "%)
        </td>
        <td width=\"25%\" align=\"right\" style=\"font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #252525;padding: 10px;padding-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;\">
            3,000 THB
        </td>
    </tr>";
}
```

EDIT:

I tried a whole bunch of other solutions including echoing the result twice with 2 variables for the color, but nothing works. One thing that I do see though is that every row has the same integer value, meaning the `$i` variable does NOT increment after each while, leading me to believe that is an issue with the Mysqli While Loop itself.

I used various fetches including `while ($row8 = mysqli_fetch_array($result8)) {` and `while ($row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc()) {` but no result. Help please?

[image]

Comment: only color does not work?, could you view the source and see the results of the color?

Comment: the source shows the same color for each row, meaning there is a problem with the integer increment, which shouldn't be.

Comment: so weird i test your code here in local machine with dummy data and it's work

Comment: I tried a whole bunch of different options, including echoing the code twice with different variable colors, but no effect. Not sure why this works on your system but not on mine. There is no CSS interfering either, its all inline.

Answer (score 0):

You have entered a wrong attribute in html ‍‍`bgcolor`.
You have the `background-color` feature
Use in `style` like this :
`$i=0`
`if ($i % 2 == 0) { $bgcolor = "#FFFFFF"; } else { $bgcolor = "#EEEEEE"; }`
`$i++;`

```
 <tr style=\"-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color:$bgColor\">
```

Comment: tried both options, neither works. It should not matter whether its `bgcolor` or in `style`, the change of color via the integer does not seem to happen.

Comment: I tested the code,the number is made correctly.